# Class static variables reset when I call them in other file

Tags: php, variables

I am practicing PHP, and the issue I encountered today is my static variable getting reset every time I call it.

Login Page after verfied user from DB

```
<?php
Session::onlogin(1);
?>
```

This is my session class it has a func onlogin and I send some data to it from another file which change `$is_signed` to true. But the issue is variable `$is_signed` getting reset when I call it from index.php it returns false

```
<?php
class Session {

private static $is_signed = false;

function __construct(){
    session_start();
}

public static function is_signed_in(){
    return self::$is_signed;
}

public static function onLogin($userid){
    if($userid){
        session_regenerate_id();
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;
        self::$is_signed = true;
        return true;
    }
}
}
$session = new Session;
?>
```

Now I am calling it in index.php as below

```
if(Session::is_signed_in()){
    echo "logged In";
}
else {
echo "error";
?>
```

I don't know where I am creating any error but when I call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

So i asume this

class.php

```
class Session
{

    private static $is_signed = false;

    function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
    }

    public static function is_signed_in()
    {
        return self::$is_signed;
    }

    public static function onLogin($userid)
    {
        if ($userid) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $userid;
            self::$is_signed = true;
            return true;
        }
    }
}
$session = new Session;
```

login.php

```
<?php

require 'class.php';
$session = new Session;
Session::onlogin(1);
var_dump(Session::is_signed_in());// output true
```

index.php

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);
require 'class.php';

var_dump(Session::is_signed_in());// output false
```

think about it that login.php and index.php are 2 separate programs not aware one of each other.Thats why you try put SESSION there change

```
    function __construct()
    {
        session_start();
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
            self::$is_signed = true;
        }
    }
```

and you are done

Comment: private static function login($userid){
        global $session;
        
        return (!$userid) ? false : $session->onLogin($userid);
    }
I call it when username and pass verified from db and I pass in the userid from DB

Comment: edit post add more code its stil unclear to be able to help

Comment: Im temted to say try coment this session_regenerate_id(); but realy not geting your question,without proper code showcase

Comment: I have edited but its simple I call onlogin(1) and it sets the $is_signed to true but then when i call it in index it seems false

Comment: how scripts are loaded,in what order? if i put all in one file it works fine

Comment: i have a init.php for that includes all the files. and backup i register spl_autoload that requires all the files